# symfony2.8をサクラレンタルサーバーで使えますか？

Tags: php, symfony2

symfony2.8でSNSの開発を行っています。
現在はwindowsマシンにxamppを入れて動かしていますが、将来レンタルサーバーを借りて公開したいと思っています。
出来れば、サクラレンタルサーバーのような安いサーバーを借りて運用したいのですが可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

サクラサーバー（スタンダードプラン）の環境でテストする機会をもらえたので試しました。
app/config.phpでみた結果、行けそうな感じでした。

Comment: 質問者のtomoyukiさんと回答者のtomoyuki yamakoshiさんは同じ方でしょうか？マージしたいなら[お問い合わせ](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)から連絡するとマージしてもらえます。参考: [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) 違うようならすみません。

Comment: すいません。おっしゃる通り同一人物です。アカウントをマージしました。